# Can't release to Internal Testing because stuck on Ready to Send For Review

Tags: android, google-play, release

Every time I add a release to Internal Testing in Google Play Console it now just sits there saying "Ready to send for review" instead of "Available to internal testers". I've checked with my own tester account and only the older release will download. I don't want the app reviewed by Google right now, I want QA to test it first. What is going on?

Comment: You need to send it for review from "Publishing overview" section

Comment: @MayurRaval I don't want it reviewed. I want it released to internal testing so QA can test it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question so I'll post it for anyone else having trouble.

tldr; Look for emails from Google that are sent only to the person with Owner status.

Our app was flagged for review because of policy violations. These are visible in the Play Console under Policy Status in the sidebar. One of these violations we fixed but it turned out there was a second one that wasn't listed because we were informed of it only in an email reply that went to the account owner. The account owner is my boss's boss's boss who gets a million emails a day and the information was never forwarded to me.